# How to set predefined value for a field in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am creating an application which contains questions and answers(objective type) , so that i vl store question and 4 answers in questions table and i will store the correct answer in answers table

Structure of tables

**questions**

```
id int(4) primary key
question text
answer1 text
answer2 text
answer3 text
answer4 text
```

**answers**

```
id int(4) Foreign Key
answer int(1)
```

now what i need is in answers table the value for answer should be only (1 or 2 or 3 or 4) so i have to predefine it and the user should not enter other value...
How to Do This...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enum` or `set` for predefined permitted values:

like: `answers ENUM('1','2','3','4')`

see: [mysql SET & ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-enum.html)